# Accessibility Voiceover focus issue in SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swiftui, accessibility, voiceover

In swiftUI how to move focus to required view. After click on one button api is getting called and view is refreshing, but after that focus is moving back to top left corner of view. i want that focus to stay on same button.

Comment: there is no focus possibility in iOS-SwiftUI at first place to set on some object,  do you working on macOS?

Comment: @swiftPunk I am working on ios app. In some situation i need accessibility voice over focus to stay on same object even after page refresh. Is is possible? or can i move focus to particular object or view programatically?

Comment: As I said there is no focus possibility exist in SwiftUI-iOS for us as Xcode user to use it!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately SwiftUI does not support focus state in iOS less than 15. You can use their [API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/menu/focused(_:)) which is supported in IOS 15 only. The other option will be to use UIKit based component and manage focus but this will be lot of work depending on your UI design and components.